# SQL alter schema multiple tables at once

Tags: sql, sql-server, schema, alter

I recently upsized my MS-Access database to SQL Server and in the process successfully exported a bunch of tables.

However, now the imported tables are prefixed with `MSH-CHAMBERS\mfanimpela` which I assume is my username and this is the schema (or owner property).

While I have seen posts on changing EACH table schema to the desired 'dbo', I want a statement that can help me change ALL of my tables (since these are so many).

Please help - chagbert.

Answer (score 1):

Use the sp_MSForEachTable procedure like this:

```
EXEC **sp_MSForEachTable** 'ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER ?'
```

*-- in the above example **dbo** is the targeted schema where you want to place your tables*

Answer (score 0):

Google `sp_MSForEachTable` and use it to call `sp_rename`

You might need to do additional checks before you rename the table to avoid mistakes.